# Python - TypeError: unbound method

Tags: python, initialization, attributeerror

So this Python problem has been giving me problems since I've tried refactoring the code into different files.  I have a file called object.py and in it, the related code is:

```
class Object:
#this is a generic object: the player, a monster, an item, the stairs...
#it's always represented by a character on screen.
def __init__(self, x, y, char, color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.char = char
    self.color = color

def move(self, dx, dy):
    #move by the given amount, if the destination is not blocked
    #if not map[self.x + dx][self.y + dy].blocked:
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
```

Now, when I try to compile this file specifically I get this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Object instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

The code that is attempting to call this is:

```
player = object_info.Object.__init__(BurglaryConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH/2, BurglaryConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, '@', libtcod.white)
```

Which causes this error when compiling:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Object'
```

So what the heck is going on with all this and how should I be refactoring this?  Also I assume having a class called Object isn't a very good coding practice, correct?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

You are defining `Object` in a file called `object.py`. And yet the client refers to `object_info.Object`. Is this a typo?

> Also I assume having a class called Object isn't a very good coding practice, correct?

Correct. Rename your class to something else, say `GenericObject` or `GenericBase`. Also don't use the module name `object.py`. Change it appropriately.

**Also**

You are constructing an instance of `Object` but the way you are doing it is wrong. Try this:

```
player = object_info.Object(BurglaryConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH/2, BurglaryConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, '@', libtcod.white)
```

This [chapter](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) from Dive Into Python should prove useful.

Comment: This didn't quite work, I still got the same AttributeError when compiling.

Comment: I actually imported object as object_info so that wasn't the problem.

However I realized I was importing the file that calls object.py in the object.py file, which I assume is a big no no, as removing it caused the error to no longer occur.

Answer (score 1):

First, always use new-style classes, i.e. inherit from `object`. (This is not needed if you are running Python 3, which has only new-style classes)

Second, calling `__init__` is very likely wrong here - if you want to instanciate a new Object, just write `Object(x, y, char, color)`.