# Python TypeError unbound method must be called with instance as first argument

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a blackjack function that draws two cards then totals the amount. I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/PycharmProjects/BlackJack/PlayBlackJack.py", line 36, in <module>
game()
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/PycharmProjects/BlackJack/PlayBlackJack.py", line 29, in game
    card1 = Deck.deal()
TypeError: unbound method deal() must be called with Deck instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Here is my full code.

```
class Card(object):

    '''A simple playing card. A Card is characterized by two 
    components:
    rank: an integer value in the range 2-14, inclusive (Two-Ace)
    suit: a character in 'cdhs' for clubs, diamonds, hearts, and
    spades.'''

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    SUITS = 'cdhs'
    SUIT_NAMES = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']

    RANKS = range(2,15)
    RANK_NAMES = ['Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six',
              'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 
              'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
    RANK_VALUES = [99, 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):

        '''Constructor
        pre: rank in range(1,14) and suit in 'cdhs'
        post: self has the given rank and suit'''

        self.rank_num = rank
        self.suit_char = suit


    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def getSuit(self):

        '''Card suit
        post: Returns the suit of self as a single character'''

        return self.suit_char

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def getRank(self):

        '''Card rank
        post: Returns the rank of self as an int'''

        return self.rank_num

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def getCardValue(self):
        value = self.RANK_VALUES[self.rank_num]
        return value

    #------------------------------------------------------------
    def suitName(self):

        '''Card suit name
        post: Returns one of ('clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts',
              'spades') corrresponding to self's suit.'''

        index = self.SUITS.index(self.suit_char)
        return self.SUIT_NAMES[index]        

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def rankName(self):

        '''Card rank name
        post: Returns one of ('ace', 'two', 'three', ..., 'king')
              corresponding to self's rank.'''

        index = self.RANKS.index(self.rank_num)
        return self.RANK_NAMES[index]

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def __str__(self):

        '''String representation
        post: Returns string representing self, e.g. 'Ace of Spades' '''

        return self.rankName() + ' of ' + self.suitName()

    #------------------------------------------------------------

from random import randrange
from Card import Card
from Hand import Hand


class Deck(object):

def __init__(self):
    '''This creates the deck of cards, un-shuffled.'''
    cards = []
    for suit in Card.SUITS:
        for rank in Card.RANKS:
            cards.append(Card(rank,suit))
    self.cards = cards

def size(self):
    '''How many cards are left.'''
    return len(self.cards)

def deal(self):
    '''Deals a single card.
    Pre: self.size() > 0
    Post: Returns the next card in self, and removes it from self.'''
    return self.cards.pop()

def shuffle(self):
    '''This shuffles the deck so that the cards are in random order.'''
    n = self.size()
    cards = self.cards
    for i,card in enumerate(cards):
        pos = randrange(i,n)
        cards[i] = cards[pos]
        cards[pos] = card

def takeAHit(self, whatHand):
    aCard = self.deal()
    whatHand.addCard(aCard)
def __str__(self):
    if self.size() == 52:
        return 'The Deck is Full'
    elif self.size() > 0:
        return 'The Deck has been Used'
    else:
        return 'The Deck is Empty'


from Card import Card

class Hand(object):

"""A labeled collection of cards that can be sorted"""

#------------------------------------------------------------

def __init__(self, label=""):

    """Create an empty collection with the given label."""

    self.label = label
    self.cards = []

#------------------------------------------------------------

def add(self, card):

    """ Add card to the hand """

    self.cards.append(card)

#------------------------------------------------------------

def handTotal(self):
    totalHand = 0
    aceAmount = 0

    for c in self.cards:
        if c.getRank() == 14:
            aceAmount += 1
            totalHand +=c.getCardValue()
    while aceAmount > 0:
        if totalHand > 21:
            aceAmount -= 1
            totalHand -= 10
        else:
            break
    return totalHand

def __str__(self):
 if self.cards == []:
    return "".join([(self.label), "doesn't have any cards."])
    tempStringList = [ self. label, "'s Cards,  "]
    for c in self.cards:
        tempStringList.append(str(c))
        tempStringList.append(" , ")

        tempStringList.pop()
        tempStringList.append(" . ")

        return "".join(tempStringList)




from Deck import Deck
from Card import Card
from Hand import Hand

def rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal):
if playerTotal > 21:
    print "You busted!"
    if dealerTotal == 21:
        print 'To make it worse, dealer has 21.'
elif dealerTotal > 21:
    print "The Dealer has busted. You win!"
elif playerTotal == 21:
    print " You got 21! So you win!"
    if dealerTotal == 21:
        print "The Dealer also got 21. Tough Break."
elif dealerTotal == 21:
    print "The Dealer got 21! Tough Break, you lose!"
else:
    if playerTotal > dealerTotal:
        print "You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk."
    if playerTotal == dealerTotal:
        print "It is a push, no one wins!"
    else:
        print "Dealer wins! Better luck next time loser."
def game():
    gameDeck = Deck()
    gameDeck = gameDeck.shuffle()
    player = raw_input("What is your name?")
    card1 = Deck.deal()
    card2 = Deck.deal()
    playerHand = Hand(player)
    playerHand = playerHand.add(card1,card2)
    print playerHand.totalHand()
    print gameDeck
```

Is there something I am missing cause I am really confused about this.
EDIT: I keep getting this error now.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/PycharmProjects/BlackJack/PlayBlackJack.py", line 33, in <module>
    print gameDeck.deal()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'deal'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Fix thy indent please!

Comment: This is more-or-less a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558937/python-typeerror-unbound-method and dozens more.

Answer (score 3):

*Deck* is a class - not an object

```
gameDeck.deal()
```

will work

Let me elaborate some - calling class as a function *Deck()* creates object of the class, through which class method may be called - as above.

*Deck* is a reference to class  - and only classmethods may be called through class reference.

Quick explanation about "**number of arguments**". Unlike C++ **this**, Python does not have reserved word for object instance within methods. You have to define it explicitly in method definition - the ubiquitous **self** (which is actually a convention, not a reserved word).

So, when you call a method of an object - e.g.

```
playerHand.add(card1)
```

*playerHand* is the first argument and *card1* is the second

About indents - they may be OK in your code, but they do not look right here. Maybe, there are tabs in your code? Those must be replaced by spaces. Google how

Comment: When I try that i get this error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'deal'

Comment: @CooperGay, fix your indents and place full exception traceback in the question

Comment: Thanks for helping me out i figured out what to do thanks to you. Is there anyway you could help me with one other problem? I'm trying to add up the totals of the cards in my hand, do you know a way I could do that? I tried appending card 1 and card 2 into a list but it prints out a weird location rather than the total.

Comment: @CooperGay, you are adding to cards at once, Both methods _Hands.add_ and _list.append_ take 1 parameter - and you call _playerHand.add(card1,card2)_. Your offsets are still off and you code looks no different than before. You have obviously invested some time - but it is impossible to help unless you fix your code as you advance. You may post fixed code as an answer - but please, handle indents!

Comment: What do you mean by indents? I thought I indenting my code. Also, whenever to do _playerHand.add(card1,card2)_, I get an error saying that it only takes 2 arguments. So when I do _playerHand.add(card1)_, I get this to be printed. `<Hand.Hand object at 0x01E7FC90> `